# Ubuntu18.04 login loop problem

Tags: login

I tried almost everything to resolve the login loop problem. But it doesn't work.

`chown .Xautority`  and `/tmp` is okay, `dpkg-reconfigure lightdm` doesn't work.

One of my clues is that I can see `--user not found` error in `.xsession-errors` file
when I log in `tty` (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd>).

Can anyone help me resolve this?

---

It still has a problem. I attached the screen `.xsession-error`.

It can have typo since I changed the screen picture to text.

```
systemd --user not found, ignoring --systemd argument
setting DISPLAY=:1
emphasized textsetting XAUTHORITY=//.Xauthority
systemd --user not found, ignoring --systemd argument 
setting GTK_MODULES=gail:atk-bridge
systemd --user not found, ignoring --systemd argument 
setting QT_ACCESSIBILITY=1
systemd --user not found, ignoring --systemd argument 
setting SUDO_GID=1000
setting MAIL=/var/mailiroot
setting USER=root
setting LANGUAGE=en_US:
setting LC_TIME=ko_KR.UTF-8
setting SHLVL=1
setting HOME=/
setting OLDPWD=/
setting GTK_MODULES=gail:atk-bridge
setting LC_MONETARY=ko_KR.UTF-8
setting DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:abstract=Stmp/dbus-5g9m8q6Iuw,guid=c36 
setting SUDO_UID=1000
sett ing IM_CONFIG_PHASE=1
sett ing LOGNAME=root
setting _=/usr/bin/startx
setting USERNAME=root
setting TERM=linux
setting WINDONPATH=3
setting PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:,usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
setting LC_ADDRESS=Ko_KR.UTF-8
setting DISPLAY=:1
setting LANG=en_US.UTF-8
setting LC_TELEPHONE=ko_KR.UTF-8
setting XAUTHORITY=//.Xauthority
setting SUDO_COMMAND=/bin/bash
setting LC_NAHE=ko_KR.U17-8
setting SHELL=/bin/bash
setting QTACCESSIBILITY=1
setting SUDO_USER=kzi
setting LC_MEASUREMENTIgkO_KR.UTP•11
sett ing LC_IDENTIF ICATION=MLICR UTP•••
setting GPG_AGENT_INFO=//.gnupg/S.gpg-agent:0:1
setting JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle 
etting PWP=/home
setting XDG_DATA_DIRS=/usr/share/gnome:/usr/local/share/:/usr/share
```

Comment: Did you make a change in the session (or two) before you had the login loop?  Have you checked you have space in $HOME (your user directory; as if the GUI cannot create work files needed for your desktop, login fails & you are logged out without message). I don't see what `dpkg-reconfigure lightdm` would do, as 18.04 uses `gdm3` by default & why did you want to re-run the post-install script for lightdm?  What made you think it was involved?  ie. background for your issue can be useful.

Comment: Please also post a larger fragment of your `.xsession-errors` file so we can see the messages in context

Comment: Thanks for the response. It's all of sudden. It just repeats the login loop. So I login by tty to see error log and the below is in .xsession-error. As you expected, there is no $USER directory in /home.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this thing by following steps:

1. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>  then enter your username and password.
2. `sudo apt -f install`
3. `sudo dpkg --configure -a`
4. `sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm`
5. `sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm`
6. `sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm3`
7. `sudo mv .Xauthority .Xauthority.bak`
8. `sudo reboot`
9. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>  then enter your username and password.
10. `sudo apt update`
11. `sudo apt upgrade`
12. `sudo reboot`
13. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>  then enter your username and password.
14. `sudo dpkg --configure -a`
15. `sudo apt -f install`
16. `sudo reboot`

After all these steps, if you are still facing the problem, post the errors and error logs you see.